# Adding custom css to React-Bootstrap Component

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-component

How to add some custom CSS styles to the Nav component to manage the padding between the nav items and make it float right of the page?

```
const navbar = props => (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#features">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">About Us</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Facilities" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Library</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Laboratories</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Transportation</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Hostel</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Gallery</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Event</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);
```

Comment: Do you want the navbar items to be displayed from right to left instead of left to right?

Answer (score 2):

you would need to override the default CSS of bootstrap, you could check the class names using the inspector of your browser and modify those classes since the react-bootstrap compiles to bootstrap anyways

create a css file called 
**Navbar.css**

```
 .navbar-nav {
  float: right !important;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

import it into **navbar.js** component

```
import "./Navbar.css";
    const navbar = props => (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#features">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">About Us</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Facilities" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Library</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Laboratories</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Transportation</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Hostel</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Gallery</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Event</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);
```